# SQLite - What are .acd, .ard and related file types?

Tags: sqlite, files

I'm using a SQLite database, and the main database file is:

```
Config.acd
```

and there are also files named:

```
Config.acd-shm
Config.acd-wal
```

What is the .acd file type, what are those variants (acd-shm, acd-wal), and why is the main file not a .db file?

I also have the following files, what are these:

```
Raw.ard
Raw.ard-shm
Raw.ard-wal
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-wal` and `-shm` files are used to store data when the DB is in [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

SQLite does not require any specific file name or extension. These file names are chosen by the program that created the database.